# Is it required to use choice principles to prove that any linearly independent set can be extended to a basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, axiom-of-choice

Let $V$ be a vector space. In order to show that any linearly independent set in $V$ can be extended to form a basis, or equivalently, any basis of a subspace of $V$ can be extended to a basis of $V$, is it required to use choice principles (i.e. Axiom of Choice or weaker forms of Choice). If so, what is the weakest choice principle that can prove this statement?

Comment: If $V$ is finite dimensional, then AC is not required. But it is needed for infinite dimensional spaces (e.g. $\mathbb{R}$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$ vector space)

Comment: @daruma If you can prove a choice-free argument for the finite-dimensional case I would accept your answer. Currently, the only proof I can think of requires choice...

Comment: It is equivalent to full choice.

Comment: Mea culpa. I thought there is a simple duplicate target, but I can't find any.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I found some similar questions but not an answer to this one...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just the existence of a basis for every vector space is enough to conclude the axiom of choice, as one can extend the empty set (or any singleton, except $\{0\}$).

Answer (score 4):

For the finite-dimensional case: If the linearly independent set is not a basis, there is a vector that it does not span i.e. that is linearly independent of it. Thus, we can increase the size of the linearly independent set by adding this vector to it. By induction, we can increase its size as long as it is not a basis. Since the vector space is finite-dimensional, this process must terminate in a basis.

Comment: This seems to be arguing that choice implies a basis, while the question is asking whether there always being a basis implies choice.

Comment: @Acccumulation You don't need AC for this argument. So it answers the OP's request in the comments for a "choice-free argument for the finite-dimensional case".

Comment: You say that there is a vector that it does not span. But don't you have to choose such a vector?

Comment: @Acccumulation: Yes, but that's a finite choice (in fact a single choice); you don't need the axiom of choice for that; it can be proved in ZF that a finite collection of sets has a choice function; see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice#Restriction_to_finite_sets).